# Converting bitshifted numbers back to their original index

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I have an Enumeration tagged with `[Flags]` that looks a bit like this:

```
    None = 1 >> 1,              // 0
    Monday = 1,                 // 1
    Tuesday = 1 << 1,           // 2
    Wednesday = 1 << 2,         // 4
    Thursday = 1 << 3,          // 8
    Friday = 1 << 4,            // 16
    Saturday = 1 << 5,          // 32
    Sunday = 1 << 6,            // 64
    FirstWeek = 1 << 7,         // 128
    SecondWeek = 1 << 8,        // 256
    ThirdWeek = 1 << 9,         // 512
    FourthWeek = 1 << 10        // 1024
```

If we just assume that the number we're shifting by is N, I need to be able to do this (pseudo ahead):

```
    function convert(MyEnum flags) {
        return flags >> n;
    }
```

Without knowing for definite what the value of MyEnum is. Is this possible?
The reason I need the Nth index is simply because I need to be able to convert between two enums - this one, and one that isn't `[Flags]` tagged, but indexed 1 - 7 (for each day).

How can I do this?

Clarification:
I need to be able to go from `flags = ThirdWeek (equal to 1 << 9)` to 10 (`N (which is 9) + 1`)

I solved this by doing:

```
 int base = (int)Math.Log((double)flags;
```

Comment: Maybe you could give an example conversion?

Comment: Sure. Edited original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know for sure that the number is a power of two, you can solve this problem by counting trailing zeros, like this:

```
uint v;
uint c = 32;
v &= (0-v);
if (v != 0) c--;
if ((v & 0x0000FFFF) != 0) c -= 16;
if ((v & 0x00FF00FF) != 0) c -= 8;
if ((v & 0x0F0F0F0F) != 0) c -= 4;
if ((v & 0x33333333) != 0) c -= 2;
if ((v & 0x55555555) != 0) c -= 1;
```

This code is [taken from here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightParallel).

Comment: Does this work in C#? either way I'm using logarithms to find the answer but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @DanPantry Now it does :) If you do not use numbers higher than 2^16, you could replace `32` with `16`, remove the upper halves of constants, and drop the first row (with `c -= 16).

Comment: That wouldn't work as-is in C#, `unsigned int` should be `uint` and `-signed(v)` should (sadly) be `0 - v`.

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to mention the other problem: `v & 0x0000FFFF != 0` etc should be `(v & 0x0000FFFF) != 0` (due to the low precedence of `&`)

Comment: Just to let you know, this has now made it into my extension method library.. :b

Answer (score 1):

Logarithms. I wish I paid more attention in math.

```
    None = 1 >> 1,              // 0
    Monday = 1,                 // 1
    Tuesday = 1 << 1,           // 2
    Wednesday = 1 << 2,         // 4
    Thursday = 1 << 3,          // 8
    Friday = 1 << 4,            // 16
    Saturday = 1 << 5,          // 32
    Sunday = 1 << 6,            // 64
    FirstWeek = 1 << 7,         // 128
    SecondWeek = 1 << 8,        // 256
    ThirdWeek = 1 << 9,         // 512
    FourthWeek = 1 << 10        // 1024

    function convert(MyEnum flags) {
         return Math.Log((int)flags, 2);
    }
```

For clarification I did actually search but I had forgotten the name of what I was trying to do.

Comment: Logarithms are good, but they are slower than manipulation on integers.

Comment: Speed isn't really a concern, it's not a high-performance project anyway :)

Comment: Then you could do a simple loop - coders who didn't pay much attention to math in school would have easier time understanding it.

Comment: Ignorance is not an excuse IMO :b

Comment: Is the float math guaranteed to return the exact result?! I would not trust this.